# How to resize a Canvas app on Salesforce?

Tags: canvas, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am creating canvas app on salesforce. I want to resize the canvas app on click of a button. I have been passing the client obj which gets returned from POST request on salesforce.

Below is the snippet:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sdk/js/canvas-all.js></script>
  $(document).on('click','.expand',function () {
  var clientObj = $('.salesforce-data').data('client');
    Sfdc.canvas(function  () {
      Sfdc.canvas.client.resize(clientObj, {height :"1000px", width :"1000px"});
     });     
    });
```

clientObj refers to which is being retrieved on POST REQUEST from salesforce.

```
"client": {
  "refreshToken": "xxxxx",
   "instanceId": "xxxx",
   "targetOrigin":"xxxx",
   "instanceUrl":"xxxx",
   "oauthToken":"xxxxx"
 }
```

correct me where I am going wrong here. I want the resize or autogrow functionality to work on canvas.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Sfdc.canvas.client.resize()` directly instead of passing it as a callback to `Sfdc.canvas()`. So the code you have inside of your event handler should look something like this:

```
var clientObj = $('.salesforce-data').data('client');

Sfdc.canvas.client.resize(clientObj, {height :"1000px", width :"1000px"});
```